# Extracting all <script> tags with a specific type

Tags: javascript

I currently have JavaScript code that is capable of extracting the inner HTML from specific tags... I'd like to extrapolate this and change it such that it can target `<script>` tags with a specific `type` attribute... For example, `type="text/testlang"`. I'm planning on using this as part of a library for a test client-side language compiler, so I don't want to rely on third-party libraries like jQuery to do the grunt work...

The code is as follows:

```
var testlang_ext = function() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (idx = arr.length; idx--;) {
      arr[idx].innerHTML = testLangConvert(arr[idx].childNodes[0].data);
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can expand this to target only script tags with a `type` of `text/testlang`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  `querySelectorAll` with attribute selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/testlang"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let testLangScripts = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script')).filter(e => e.getAttribute('type') === 'text/testlang')
```